# Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (512,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

Having trouble with the error in the title. I do actually know why I'm receiving this error but after researching I struggle to understand the concept as I'm new to ML. The error is relating to not having X_TRAIN and Y_TRAIN but I'm unable to understand what they consist of. All images have been resized to the same dimensions. I'm using the CUB 2011 dataset with a split of 90:10 training/validation, here is my code below that relates to the error. I'm using Keras.

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape = (467,386,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))

#Smaller for precise pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

#Add 512 unit layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu'))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, which does *not* work by throwing all of our code as-is. What is the full error message and *where exactly* in your code does it pop up? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as [why a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: @desertnaut the error message is in the subject, and the location/cause of error is  commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the discrepancy between your final `Dense(512, ...)` layer and the fact that your data targets are just 1 dimension. You can either fix by converting the model to output the expected dimensions, or adjust the data to the expected model outputs. That depends on what you are trying to achieve. To fix the model you can add another `Dense` layer:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 512, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2)) #prevent overfitting
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')) # HERE ---
```

Or have a look at the what generator is outputting by `print(next(train_generator))` to see why the target array is 1 dimensional.

Comment: This worked for me, however may I ask does this affect the accuracy in any way? Is adding this dense layer any better/worse than using an nparray of x_train and y_train?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve, blindly matching the shapes until it works is not a strategy. To answer your case, it shouldn't too much, you just added the output layer, most of the capacity of the network comes from the hidden layer with 512 dimensions.